# How to give multiple conditions in *ngIf statement in angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

My navigation bar,

```
<div *ngIf = ("path == '/login'" && "path == '/home'") class="tabs-header-nav">
<a routerLink="/login" class="nav-link active">login</a>
<a routerLink="/bb" class="nav-link">home</a>
<a routerLink="/" class="nav-link">CC</a>
</div>

 <div *ngIf = ("path == '/aa'" || "path == '/bb'") class="tabs-header-nav">
<a routerLink="/aa" class="nav-link active">aa</a>
<a routerLink="/bb" class="nav-link">bb</a>
<a routerLink="/" class="nav-link">CC</a>
</div>
```

Likewise I have 5 to 6 navigation bar in my html. Now I need to display a particular navigation bar for particular page. Single if condition ( *ngIf = "path === '/aa'" ) seems to be working, where if I give multiple conditions it is not working. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Checkout `NgSwitch`

Comment: Can you give an example of what exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You should go for [`ngSwitch`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch) that takes multiple values

```
<div [ngSwitch]="path">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'/login'">...</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'/home'">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mff7k4?file=src/app/test/test.component.html) demo here

I think you are doing mistake in *ngIf quotations

Comment: You created are correct on stackblitz. But add what you added in stackblitz here.

Comment: added complete code and explain every step is quite time taken, that's why i added the demo directly...demo always be better.  you understand what i did..?

Comment: ok bro.But somene see your answer.Did you know what he say?.Following like he will say and downvote. While may link also have answer please add some code here.

Comment: But i will appreciate for your valuable time for answer then only iam upvote for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have data that may in every time be different, mostly you use of `If`. but if is not ok in every where. It is better that you use of `switch-case` in your code like:

```
public string TestSwitchCase(string value)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case "John":
                return null;
            case "Jack":
                return "Jack";
            default:
                break;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Now in angular, there is best way to do this in `HTML` code. this is `ngSwitch` and use like:

```
<container-element [ngSwitch]="switch_expression">
 <some-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_1">...</some-element>
 <some-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_2">...</some-element>
 <some-other-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_3">...</some-other-element>
 <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_3">
    <!-- use a ng-container to group multiple root nodes -->
       <inner-element></inner-element>
       <inner-other-element></inner-other-element>
       </ng-container>
       <some-element *ngSwitchDefault>...</some-element>
</container-element>
```

For more information See: [This](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch)

GoodLuck.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLUTION] : Simply use "&&" operator to add multiple conditions in *ngIf -

```js
//TypeScript File - demo.ts

   //Declaration
   flag: any;
   temp_array = [];

   //Assignment
   this.flag = true;
   this.temp_array = [1,2];
```

```html
<!--HTML File - demo.html-->
  
  <div *ngIf="flag && temp_array.length>0">
    Both *ngIf conditions passes
  </div>
```